# How to add swap to ZFS disk?

Tags: solaris, opensolaris

I installed Solaris 10 05/09 on a machine and I used whatever the default swap space setting when I built the box.  Now I need to increase the swap space and I can't add a swap file, like was possible under UFS.  How can I increase the amount of swap on my ZFS drive?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If your swap device is in use, then you might not be able to delete it. Check to see if the swap area is in use. For example:

```
$ swap -l
swapfile                 dev    swaplo   blocks     free
/dev/zvol/dsk/rpool/swap 182,2         8  4194296  4194296
```

In the above output, blocks == free, so the swap device is not actually being used.

If the swap area is not is use, remove the swap area. For example:

> $ swap -d /dev/zvol/dsk/rpool/swap

Confirm that the swap area is removed.

```
$ swap -l
No swap devices configured
```

Resize the swap volume. For example:

```
$ zfs set volsize=1G rpool/swap
```

One also has to ensure that the referenced swap is reserved from the pool, otherwise when it comes time to swap there might not be enough memory:

```
$ zfs set refreservation=1G rpool/swap
```

Activate the swap area.

```
$ swap -a /dev/zvol/dsk/rpool/swap

$ swap -l
swapfile                 dev    swaplo   blocks     free
/dev/zvol/dsk/rpool/swap 182,2         8  2097144  2097144
```

More info at: [ZFS Troubleshooting Guide](http://www.solarisinternals.com/wiki/index.php/ZFS_Troubleshooting_Guide)

Comment: So refreservation makes sure the normal files doesn't take up the SWAP?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: yes, refreservation ensures that rpool/swap will be allocated space from the pool even if it is unused.

Answer (score 2):

If your swap is active, you can add an additional swap volume.

zfs create -V 10G rpool/swap2

swap -a /dev/zvol/dsk/rpool/swap2